# C# best way to handle exeception retry for n times sending message to queue using polly

Tags: c#-4.0, async-await, rabbitmq, masstransit, polly

I am publish message to queue using MassTransit and RabbitMQ. 
Can anyone tell me what is the best way to handle exception if there is no queue available and try for n times using Polly?

here is my code to publish message to queue:

```
private async Task PublishToQueue(ChangeDetected changeDetected)
{
    _logProvider.Info("Publish to Queue started");

    try
    {
       await _busControl.Publish(changeDetected);

        _logProvider.Info($"ChangeDetected message published to RabbitMq. Message");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logProvider.Error("Error publishing message to queue: ", ex);

        throw;
    }
}
```

Can i use the following code in the quartz.net job to implement polly retry?

```
                //Publish message to queue
                Policy
                    .Handle<Exception>()
                    .RetryAsync(_configReader.RetryLimit, (exception, count) =>
                    {
                        //Do something for each retry
                    })
                    .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        await PublishToQueue(message);
                    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, does it work?

Comment: this policy worked in some other scenario. but not sure how to test while publishing message to queue. because any object passed to publish method seems to works and the Publish method doesnt seems to be throwing any exception. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi @MukilDeepthi  The pattern is certainly possible (we do exactly this pattern with Polly, EasyNetQ, RabbitMQ and some custom messaging resiliency we built).  Polly can't do anything though if MassTransit isn't indicating any error by throwing an exception.  What does their documentation say on how `Publish` indicates failure?  I'm assuming also publish isn't returning a `Task` - worth checking - if it is, you'd need to observe the Task exceptions in the normal way (and/or use `ExecuteAsync` variants in Polly).

Comment: Hi @mountaintraveller, yes the publish method return Task. Could you update the sample code with correct implementation please?

Comment: Hi @MukilDeepthi  I don't have Quartz/MassTransit to check the particular implementation locally, but in principle it looks fine: your suggested use of `RetryAsync`/`ExecuteAsync` should make Polly handle any exceptions thrown within `PublishToQueue(...)`.  What happens when you try that implementation?  The [Polly-Samples](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly-Samples) repo on github contains async samples which use the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks @mountaintraveller. My implementation seems to be working but not sure is this the right way :)

Comment: In what sense 'right'? The following could certainly be improved: (i) You _must_ also `await` or `.Wait()` (or otherwise block on) `ExecuteAsync()`.  Otherwise, nothing is observing the outcome of the `Task` which `ExecuteAsync()` returns, and you may silently lose any _final_ exception (in the case all retries fail). (ii) You want some architectural strategy for that - for when all attempts to publish message failed.  Does the publishing code take remedial action? Do you capture failed msgs somewhere special, to try publishing later? (eg in a 'message hospital', a specialised logger for this)

Comment: Some more suggestions: (iii) Consider Polly's `WaitAndRetry()` with exponential backoff.  If the failure is due to a network blip, you may be more likely to succeed with a 5, 10-second pause, than retry immediately (tho this depends on timeouts already in `_busControl.Publish` and if blocking that long is acceptable).

Comment: In my case, I only use Polly to handle RabbitMqConnectionException type exceptions that happen when RabbitMQ goes down.  For dealing with all other types of exceptions, I use MassTransit built-in re-try policy via cfg.UseRetry and handle the Fault<T> messages published by MassTransit.